# Pass an object to update fields on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript

I need to pass to the updateMany method in a Node/Typescript software a piece of query retrieved from the database:

```
{'$unset': {'extras' : {'origin': ''}}}
```

In the db, the above query is stored as a field of an Object:

```
"cleanup.aggregated_records_to_modify" : {
    "update_fields_by" : "{'$unset': {'extras' : {'origin': ''}}}"
}
```

If I pass the update_fields_by to the updateMany mondodb Nodejs driver method, I have an error saying ""MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators." (it receives a string instead of an object?!?); if, instead, I create an object variable:

```
const queryTemp = { $unset: { extras: { origin: "" } } };
```

to give to the updateMany, all goes well.
How can I retrieve the field from db and correctly pass it to the update method as an object?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JSON.parse(foo)` on your variable, to convert it from string to an object

Comment: With JSON.parse, I receive the error {"stack":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>

Comment: Try to escape your string. `JSON.parse("{\"$unset\": {\"extras\" : {\"origin\": \"\"}}}")`

Comment: Does not work:
const queryObject = JSON.parse(query.update_fields_by);
In the debug console: query.update_fields_by is: '{"\$unset": {"extras" : {"origin": ""}}}' -->> the type is string
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 3

Comment: const queryObject = JSON.parse(query.update_fields_by);
In the debug console: query.update_fields_by is: '{"\$unset": {"extras" : {"origin": ""}}}' -->> the type is string
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 3
But yes, if in the debug console I wrote:
JSON.parse('{"\$unset": {"extras" : {"origin": ""}}}')
{$unset: {…}}
$unset: {extras: {…}}
extras: {origin: ''}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
No errors raised.

Comment: I don't know if your code it's changed by copy/paste. But you have to surround your string with double quote. And have backslashes before each double quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem (a bug?) with the tool I use to manage MondoDB; I cannot store an object with a key starting with $ because I receive the error "Illegal argument: Invalid BSON field name $unset". I have add the $ symbol programmatically.